# Filter jTable data from database using jComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-8

I am new in java programming. 
I used netbeans 8.2 to create simple projects. Now, I created a `jtable` with data from database and I used `jComboBox` to filter its data.

I want the `jTable` to show data depending on the selected item of `jCombobox`.

`jComboBox` is  also connected to database but to a different table.

## My database

**Database - `sales`**

- `cat`: id, category
- `product`: id, specs, price, quantity

The `jComboBox` is connected to table `cat` and is showing the data from `category` column.

The problem is the `jTable` does not show data.

```
   package GUI;

    public class MainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    myQuery mq = new myQuery();

    public MainGUI() {
    initComponents();
    BindCombo();           
    }
    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            ArrayList <Product> list = mq.getData(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object \[\]{"id","specs","price","quantity"}); Object\[\] row = new Object\[4\];
    for (int i= 0; i < list.size();i++){
            row \[0\] = list.get(i).getId();
            row \[1\] = list.get(i).getSpecs();
            row \[2\] = list.get(i).getId();
            row \[3\] = list.get(i).getSpecs();
            model.addRow(row);
    }
    jTable1.setModel(model);
    } 
/*bind jComboBox to database table cat*/
    private void BindCombo(){
        Connection con = myQuery.Connect();
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{

            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cat");

            while(rs.next()){
                jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString(2));
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){

        }
    }                     


    public class myQuery {

    public static Connection Connect(){
    Connection conn = null;
     try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn = riverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales", "root", "");
       System.out.println("Connected");
       return conn;

      }catch(Exception e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       return null;
          }
       }
       /* fetch data from database to jTable*/
    public ArrayList<Product> getData(String category){
            ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
            Connection conn = Connect();
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;


    try{
                st = conn.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT 'id', 'specs', 'price', 'quantity' FROM 'product' WHERE 'category'");

                Product p = null;

                while(rs.next()){
                    p = new Product(
                            rs.getInt("id"),
                            rs.getString("specs"),
                            rs.getInt("price"),
                            rs.getInt("quantity")
                    );
                   list.add(p);
                }

            }catch(SQLException ex){

            }
      return list;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see from your source: a) you are using `javax.swing`, b) you connect to `mysql` database - I made edits to your question, please check my corrections.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. Where is the `initComponents()` method?

Comment: For better, sooner help, post [mcve].

Comment: As a suggestion, never Choke the `catch` clause which in case of happening exception it is good to print the stack trace otherwise you will lose the way of finding the reason of the exception if was occurred.

Comment: do you have codes for this guys? i mean filter jtable data using jcombobox. i would love to try it and study on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight first. You want to display a grid called jTable, and refresh its content whenever a change occurs in jCombobox1, correct? The WHERE clause looks suspect as there is no SARG equation (Search argument).

`rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT 'id', 'specs', 'price', 'quantity' FROM 'product' WHERE 'category'"); You need WHERE 'category' = ???`

at the VERY LEAST. In fact, the way you are iterating over the rows is very inefficient. Try to think of binding to the full SET every time instead of a "for loop."

Comment: Please format your answer to be readable by using the formating tools.

Comment: yes that's what i wanted. could you please give me the complete code. or you can fix my code above. i will appreciate that @CubeSpark

Answer (score 0):

@Abra here it is initComponents menthod

private void initComponents() {

```
        BindingAppPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BindingAppPU").createEntityManager();
        productQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : BindingAppPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p");
        productList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : productQuery.getResultList();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        categotyPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        productPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTabbedPane1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("add");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Add New Category");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                .addGap(95, 95, 95))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Available Categories");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Available Products");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 203, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(91, 91, 91))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 325, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout categotyPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(categotyPanel);
        categotyPanel.setLayout(categotyPanelLayout);
        categotyPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            categotyPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, categotyPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        categotyPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            categotyPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(categotyPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Category", categotyPanel);

        jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Category");

        jComboBox2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Name");

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("CostPrice");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("SalePrice");

        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Quantity");

        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Add");

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("Add new Product");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(139, 139, 139)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, 0, 176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(85, 85, 85))
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(225, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout productPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(productPanel);
        productPanel.setLayout(productPanelLayout);
        productPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            productPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, productPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        productPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            productPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(productPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Product", productPanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
```